# Elixir/Erlang concurrent state access

Tags: concurrency, erlang, elixir, ets

How to organize parallel access to data (e.g. ETS table) from bunch of processes in erlang or elixir?
In traditional model I would create `RWLock` and make critical section as small as possible. So, I can access to hash-table with parallel reads at least.
In erlang first idea is implement `gen_server` that store table in state. But all access will be serialized. How to handle it to serve faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use direct access to [`:ets`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html) and specify `read_concurrency: true` in call to [`:ets.new/2`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#new-2).

`GenServer` is a redundant link here, that *might* become a bottleneck.

Comment: But where to store ets table itself and how to share access to it without something like `GenServer`? Also it is might be required to serialize write access.

Comment: `:ets` table is stored in memory. To share the access use `named_table`. The documentation I linked describes it in details. If you need a distributed solution, use [`:mnesia`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html). If you need to serialize writes, use `GenServer`.